# How does word co-occurrence let two words from the same topic link together in LDA topic model?

Tags: topic-models

The essence of LDA is word co-occurrence. I want to know why? and does word co-occurrence mean two words appear together in a certain document or just appear in the documents collection together?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Have you have a look at this: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/32350/7744

Comment: Perhaps this quote will shed more light. "You shall know a word by the company it keeps" Firth, J. R.