# Topic models (LDA), word cooccurances in documents?

Tags: modeling, text-mining, topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I have read on papers that Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) works by identifying word cooccurances in documents. What is confusing me is since LDA uses bag-of-words approach for document representation word cooccurance information is lost. So what does it mean by LDA works by identifying word cooccurances to form topics?

Comment: I think you may find some answers here (not sure if it is enough for this to count as a duplicate) http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32310/topic-models-and-word-co-occurrence-methods/32350#32350

Comment: It uses co-occurence between documents.  So given words A,B,C if one document is AB and another AC, it might therefore link B and C because they both occur with A. That it is a bag of words approach just means that document  AB = BA.

Answer (score 1):

Bag-of-words means that order of words is not important. Co-occurrence does not take into account the order - so there is no contradiction.